# Defining constants inside a structure

Tags: c++, structure

Is there any special significance to defining constant data inside a structure as shown. This is from a 3rd party library.

```
typedef struct              
{           
    IntVB abc_number;           
    #define ABC_A   0x01    
    #define ADBC_E  0x02     
    IntVB asset;            
} StructA;
```

Comment: You shouldn't use macros for this in C++.

Comment: What they should be using is const definitions, which will give runtime access to the data, will be typed and will have scope.

Comment: @sbi: If you look at the typedef, it suggests to me that while the OP is in C++, the third party header originates from C.

Comment: @DeadMG: The number of questions and answers here where people mindlessly use C's `typedef struct {} blah;` syntax rather makes me suspect a 50% chance that it is indeed C++, but whoever wrote it missed more of C++ than the fact that macros are frowned upon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not really. They probably provide better significance to the programmer in that spot of the code.

Meaning that those constants are probably related to the items in that struct container, or to the behavior of the struct.

Comment: And in the case above it wont be even possible to access those constants at runtime, since they are only `#define`'s. Not sure what meaning do they have here.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with @Luca Matteis.  They are probably defined there because they are relevant at that point in the code.  The compiler doesn't treat them specially.  In particular, they could be defined just before that structure and work just the same.  There's no significance to them being inside it.

However, there is one thing to note, they are only valid *after* they are defined.  So they can't be used earlier in the file.  That could be significant.  For instance, they could be defined differently before that point.  (It's a bad idea to do that, but it's possible.)

Comment: yes true but i dont see them being redifined anywhere in the rest of the file

Answer (score 1):

No, they could be called without any scope